# Get SQL for activerecord conditions without main select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any way to get the sql for a single condition or chain of conditions so `Booking.where(active: true).to_conditional_sql` would return `WHERE bookings.active='t'` instead of `SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE bookings.active='t'`

Comment: where do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want Scopes:
You can find more about scopes here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: I want the actual sql of the scope / condition

Comment: You can just call .to_sql on any query to get the sql